# How to find out when a launchd launch agent will run next time?

Tags: launchd

On Linux, the `systemctl list-timers` command returns something like this:

```
NEXT                            LEFT LAST                              PASSED UNIT                             ACTIVATES          >
Mon 2023-11-27 16:15:11 CST       8h Sun 2023-11-26 16:15:11 CST      15h ago systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer     systemd-tmpfiles-cl>
Tue 2023-11-28 00:00:00 CST      15h Mon 2023-11-27 00:00:01 CST       8h ago shadow.timer                     shadow.service
Tue 2023-11-28 11:29:00 CST 1 day 3h Mon 2023-11-27 03:21:31 CST 4h 41min ago man-db.timer                     man-db.service
Sat 2023-12-02 21:50:24 CST   5 days Wed 2023-11-22 10:57:47 CST   4 days ago archlinux-keyring-wkd-sync.timer archlinux-keyring-w>
```

Is there any way to get the `launchctl` command to return this information—specifically, the last time a launch agent was run and the next time it will be run? The `launchctl list` command shows much less information:

```
PID     Status  Label
-       0       com.apple.SafariHistoryServiceAgent
66814   0       com.apple.progressd
19633   0       com.apple.cloudphotod
...
```